# How can I focus on one vimsplit fullscreen?

Tags: neovim, split

Say I've got three splits open with code in, and I suddenly want to make the one I'm in fullscreen, temporarily. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When focused on it, run:

```
:tabe %
```

To open a new tab with the same file. You can navigate tabs with `gT` and `gt` among other, if you want to go back to your split.

Once you are done with it, on the "fullscreen" one, run:

```
:q
```

to close the tab (technically closes the focused window, which is the only one of the tab, and closing the last window of the tab closes the tab).

Answer (score 4):

If your splits are vertical you can press `Ctrl-w|` to maximize the focused window.
If splits are horizontal then press `Ctrl-w_`. To resize the splits press `Ctrl-w=`

Comment: This is good, but unfortunately doesn’t preserve exactly the original layout